# VS Code clear previous output before each run

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, visual-glitch, vscode-code-runner

Extensions installed: Python, Code Runner

The problem is I was trying to enable the "clear previous output before each run setting"

[image]

But when I try running a simple code the output (in terminal) becomes glitchy.

The code I am running is:

```
print('hello')
a=input()
print(a)
```

Here is the first time I run the code in completely Blank terminal

[image]

The first attempt is pretty normal.

Here is the what happens when I run the code again

[image]

There is a lot of blank space in the terminal which becomes worse the third time I run the code

This blank space worsens till the 5th attempt and here is what happens on the sixth attempt.

[image]

Basically the blank space vanishes and all the previous attempts can be seen in the terminal. But that means the initial setting I intended did not apply and terminal does not get cleared before each run.

Can someone tell how to automatically clear terminal before each run.

Comment: I know I should not post images but since I am new to the site please pardon me this time, I did not know how to post my doubt without the image, although I tried writing and explaining it in text as much as possible, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true` works well in `OUTPUT` panel, but does not work in the terminal.

Someone else has submitted a feature request for it. You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/832) and upvote it.